# Error with StateTomographyFitter

Tags: qiskit, state-tomography

I am trying to perform a state tomography over a circuit of 5 qubits named `circ`.

I personally measure qubits 1,2 and 3. While the tomography is over qubits 0 and 4. Namely,

```
backend = provider.get_backend('simulator_stabilizer')
err_circ = transpile(circ, backend, layout_method='noise_adaptive')
circuits = state_tomography_circuits(err_circ, [0,5])
res = execute(circuits, backend=backend, shots=500, noise_model=None).result()
fitter = StateTomographyFitter(res, circuits)
```

Last step is where I get the following error:

```
array must not contain infs or NaNs
```

The error is caused by my measurements, but, without them, I can't perform efficient noise simulation.

Comment: Can you provide the circuit on which you perform the operation? And the version of qiskit you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this issue on my machine. And by tracing it, I found a bug in `TomographyFitter.add_data()` method where `marginal_counts` is called with wrong parameters.

As a workaround, you can create a new class which inherits from `StateTomographyFitter` and override the erroneous method:

```
from ast import literal_eval
from qiskit.ignis.verification import StateTomographyFitter
from qiskit.ignis.verification.tomography.data import marginal_counts, combine_counts

class MyStateTomographyFitter(StateTomographyFitter):
    def add_data(self, results, circuits):
        if isinstance(circuits[0], str) or len(circuits[0].cregs) == 1:
            marginalize = False
        else:
            marginalize = True

        # Process measurement counts into probabilities
        for circ in circuits:
            counts = None
            for result in results:
                counts = result.get_counts(circ)

            tup = literal_eval(circ.name)

            if marginalize:
                counts = marginal_counts(counts, range(len(tup))) # <== here
            if tup in self._data:
                self._data[tup] = combine_counts(self._data[tup], counts)
            else:
                self._data[tup] = counts
```

Now replace `StateTomographyFitter` in your code with the new class:

```
fitter = MyStateTomographyFitter(res, circuits)
```

---

**Note**: Qiskit Ignis is deprecated. You should use [Qiskit Experiments](https://qiskit.org/documentation/experiments/tutorials/state_tomography.html) instead. The following code snippet shows how to do the same task using Qiskit Experiments:

```
from qiskit_experiments.library import StateTomography

exp = StateTomography(circ, measurement_qubits = [0, 5])
data = exp.run(backend).block_for_results()
rho = data.analysis_results(0).value

from qiskit.visualization import array_to_latex
array_to_latex(rho)
```

Comment: Thank you! Would Qiskit Experiments give the same bug?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. I added a sample code to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the error you are encountering is occurring when you try to fit the results of your state tomography to a density matrix. This error typically occurs when the results of the state tomography contain infinity or NaN (not a number) values, which can happen if the measurements you performed on qubits 1, 2, and 3 were not valid.

One way to fix this error would be to ensure that the measurements you perform on qubits 1, 2, and 3 are valid. For example, you can check that the measurements are unbiased and that they are orthogonal to each other. This will ensure that the results of the state tomography are valid and can be fit to a density matrix.

Comment: Thank you, but measurements are meant to be parallel.